# Updating a @Binding value without triggering changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a struct which's init is like that

```
@Binding var fieldValue:Float

init(fieldValue:Binding<Float>) {
  self._fieldValue = fieldValue
}
```

at some point I would like to update `fieldValue` without triggering updates on other points listening to `$fieldValue`.

Is that possible?

Comment: What is it that you are using this `fieldValue` for? `Binding` should be used when you want to inject a value that can be updated both from inside and outside the view and these updates are synced between the view and whoever injects the `Binding`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that SwiftUI synchronizes all `Binding`s by default and there's no way to explicitly disable this behaviour.

However, we can work around it by wrapping the property in an `ObservableObject` and get a custom `Binding` based on the behaviour that is desired, using the `Binding(get:set:)` initializer.

(Note that this may not work well with the standard UI components, like `Slider`, as they may expect a `Binding` update in order to work correctly.)

```swift
class ValueContainer: ObservableObject {
    
    private var fieldValue: Float = 0
    
    func getBinding(isTriggering: Bool) -> Binding<Float> {
        Binding { [self] in
            self.fieldValue
        } set: { [self] newValue in
            self.fieldValue = newValue
            if isTriggering {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct DoesNotTriggerUpdate: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var container: ValueContainer
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: container.getBinding(isTriggering: false))
    }

}

struct DoesTriggerUpdate: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var container: ValueContainer
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: container.getBinding(isTriggering: true))
    }

}
```

Comment: @Bradley: the way you used could be done without using class even with a custom Binding in a View.